# why does this librosa library python cant be installed correctly?

Tags: npm-install, librosa

i tried to install librosa (python library) in the comand using
npm install librosa
but it dosent work i get this error

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/librosa - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'librosa@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-04-19T18_06_54_614Z-debug-0.log

i tried to update the version of ny npm and node.js but it wasnt solved
does someone can help me?

tried to update the npm and the node.js version

Comment: If it's a Python library, why are you trying to install it with `npm`?